# Sharepoint Keeps my login session

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, central-administration, sharepoint-on-prem, 2016

I have a very peculiar with my On Premise Sharepoint 2016 Public Website.

I built this site from scratch and had it in testing for a while until it was time to make it public and launch for my company. Upon launching, the default page for some reason displays the administrative ribbon up top, showing to the entire world that they are signed in as my user...

I tried commenting out the TrimmedSecurity Control and modifying the template, but the problem persists.

Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image: Default Page]

As opposed to all the other pages like the About, etc.

[image]

Comment: I attempted a Cache flushing solution i found where I modify the cache.ini and delete the files in the directory and then reset the file.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues I just replaced the suitebar found in my master page with this:

```
<div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
   <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server"     AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly" EmitDiv="true">
      <div id="s4-ribbonrow" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></div>
   </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
   <SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" EmitDiv="true">
      <div id="suiteBar" class="ms-dialogHidden noindex">
         <!--#suiteBarLeft and #suiteBarRight-->
      </div>
      <div id="s4-ribbonrow">
         <!--ootb ribbon controls-->
      </div>
   </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had also made this modification and the error persists.